# Can a Chrome extension receive a selection change event from the Chrome pdf viewer?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension w/ a content script that I want to do things when the selection changes (get the text, do some stuff with the text). I can do this with normal webpages by registering `document.addEventListener("selectionchange", mycode)`, and then accessing the selection with `window.getSelection()`. Is it possible to do something similar in the Chrome pdf viewer?